# Xdebug not available in Composer plugin

Tags: php, composer-php, xdebug, xdebug-3

I'm trying to debug a Composer plugin with Xdebug. I have my environment set up (`export XDEBUG_SESSION=1`) and the Xdebug loaded in `php.d`. The script breaks at first line in Composer so everything works so far.

In a `composer-plugin` class method code I add an `xdebug_break()`. What I get when that code gets executed is `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function xdebug_break()`.

Does Composer spawn a crippled shell of sorts without the environment set or runs PHP without extensions? How can I fix this to debug the Composer plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found myself the answer: As per [Xdebug documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-xdebug),

```sh
export COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1
```

did the trick.

Comment: For setting the debugging-related environment variable(s) just for the composer execution, prefix the variable(s) before the actual command, e.g.: `COMPOSER_ALLOW_XDEBUG=1 XDEBUG_SESSION=1 composer update`